# TemplateDoesNotExist в modelviewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Пытаюсь разобраться с modelviewset в drf.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from ..models import *
from ..serializers import *


class NewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MobileNewsModelSerializer
    queryset = MobileNewsModel.objects.all()
```

serializers.py

```
class MobileNewsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MobileNewsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter

router = SimpleRouter()

router.register(r'news', NewsViewSet)

urlpatterns = [path('auth/', view=views.AuthView.as_view(), name='auth'),
               path('', include(router.urls))]
```

При переходе на url /news ошибка TemplateDoesNotExist. Но при этом post-запросы на добавление новых элементов без проблем проходят. Не работает лишь get, получается

Если сделать так:

```
urlpatterns = [path('auth/', view=views.AuthView.as_view(), name='auth'),
                path('news/', view=NewsViewSet.as_view({"get": "list"}), name='news'),
               ]
```

То все прекрасно отображается. В чем может быть проблема?